# Зачем в конструкторе класса метод clone()?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Необходимо создать коллекцию, которая будет безопасно работать в многопоточной программе и будет являться общим ресурсом для потоков.

Не совсем понимаю, зачем нужен метод `clone()` в конструкторе класса и где здесь паттерн *Декоратор*.

Есть предположение, что таким образом избавляются от общего ресурса и каждый поток будет работать со своей локальной копией.

```
public class SingleLockList<T> implements Iterable<T> {
    private final List<T> list;

    public SingleLockList(List<T> list) {
        this.list = (List) list.clone();
    }

    public void add(T value) {
    }

    public T get(int index) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ваш класс будет содержать ссылку на объект переданный извне, то он не может полностью контролировать к нему доступ. В этом случае клиент этого класса может сохранить список, который он использовал для создания `SingleLockList`, у себя и использовать его для модификации и доступа.

Это позволит клиенту обходить всю логику синхронизации и ограничения совместного доступа к списку реализованную в `SingleLockList`. Чтоб этого не происходило ваш класс не может хранить ссылки на разделяемые ресурсы, а это значит должен делать копии при получении объектов и также, когда возвращает объекты (например, если есть метод типа `getList()`, то он тоже должен возвращать копию, а не оригинальный `list`.

Comment: Между тем, полагаться на `list.clone` -- плохая затея, потому что там вполне себе можно вернуть тот же самый список и клиент сможет обходить всю логику синхронизации. Надо делать своё копирование, например `this.list = new ArrayList<>(list))`